# How to obtain instagram pictures from a place consuming instagram API?

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

I gave a look to [**instafeed.js**](http://instafeedjs.com/). It works good right away, I followed the first docs and got a 20 images sample displaying at web page.

However I really need to obtain pictures from a certain place (city, in my case). Working with  Twitter API I used to look for the `WOEID` for the wanted place. Here it seems to be quite similar.

I read [Instagram docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/):

```
DISTANCE    Default is 1000m (distance=1000), max distance is 5000.
FACEBOOK_PLACES_ID  Returns a location mapped off of a Facebook places id. If used, a Foursquare id and lat, lng are not required.
FOURSQUARE_ID   Returns a location mapped off of a foursquare v1 api location id. If used, you are not required to use lat and lng. Note that this method is deprecated; you should use the new foursquare IDs with V2 of their API.
LAT Latitude of the center search coordinate. If used, lng is required.
LNG Longitude of the center search coordinate. If used, lat is required.
FOURSQUARE_V2_ID    Returns a location mapped off of a foursquare v2 api location id. If used, you are not required to use lat and lng.
```

But where the hell can I obtain such ID's for a city. Let's say I want pictures tagged with *dinner* at Puebla, Mexico. What should I do.

I used this nice site to get an ID from my coordinates: http://maihamakyo.org/etc/locastagram/index.php

Tried this Java Script code then:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
                get: 'tagged',
                location: '46016173',
                tagName: 'CLEU',
                clientId: '***'
})

feed.run();
```

but got not the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version **1.3**, you can add a filter function to Instafeed.js, to exclude images from the results.

So you should be able to set `get: "location"`, and your `locationId`, and then filter out any images that **don't** contain the tag you're looking for:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'location',
  locationId: LOC_ID,
  // other settings omitted for example
  filter: function(image) {
    return image.tags.indexOf('TAG_NAME') >= 0;
  }
});
feed.run();
```

---

**Update**

The `image` parameter that gets passed to the `filter` function is the image data straight from Instagram's API. So you can filter on any criteria you want. Just make sure the function returns `true` or `false`:

```
filter: function(image) {
  if (image.tags.indexOf('TAG_NAME') >= 0 && image.filter === "Normal") {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

To get an idea of what properties that `image` object has, check [this thread](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/21) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, you know I like instafeed a lot. Congrats for your work However I really find it lack of documentation :(

Comment: What about flitering more than 1 criteria?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example filter using multiple criteria! You're welcome to help contribute to documentation if you want to improve it :)

Comment: I'd be please, honestly I'm not a pro in Java Script but if I can help I'll be sooo pleased. May I contact you to talk a bit about it?

Comment: Sure! The best way is you start a new issue in GitHub and share your thoughts there.

Comment: would Thanks for all ! Would you mind give an eye to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905221/how-to-do-oauth-authentication-via-ajax-jquery

Comment: @StevenSchobert When you put in the locationID like this, how big is the radius of lookup in instagram?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [instafeed.js documentation](http://instafeedjs.com/#standard), the option name/key for location should be `locationId`.

I'm not familiar with the Instagram API, but the instafeed.js documentation hints heavily that `get` needs to be set to `location` to use a location ID. So it is very possible you can only search for a tag, or a location, but not both.

Comment: As of [v1.3.0](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/releases/tag/v1.3.0), you can specify a `filter` function. So you should be able to set the `get: "tagged"`, and then filter by location. Or vise-versa.

Comment: @StevenSchobert can you offer an example?

Comment: @diegoaguilar Sure! I've added an answer, that contains a code example for you!