# How to crawl shortened urls and get the actual domain in python?

Tags: python, url

I'm catching tweets from Twitter API, many times tweets contain shortened URLS, so it's really important to get the actual URL they take to.

For example, for http://t.co/3hwXTqmktt which takes to http://www.animalpolitico.com/2014/04/304037/#axzz2yETrXxui I need to obtain *animalpolitico.com*

The most important thing is to get the domain, so if I have for example:

```
http://news.example.com 

http://blog.example.com/eeaWdada5das

http://example.com/ewdaD585Jz
```

I obtain: *`example.com`* for each.

I guess any such *`curl`* for python will help. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Something to consider is that domains are not always .com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to extract domain name from the url, besides [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html), you can use [tldextract](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract) module:

```
>>> import tldextract
>>> urls = ['http://news.example.com', 
            'http://blog.example.com/eeaWdada5das', 
            'http://example.com/ewdaD585Jz']
>>> for url in urls:
...     data = tldextract.extract(url)
...     print '{0}.{1}'.format(data.domain, data.suffix)
... 
example.com
example.com
example.com
```

UPD (example for `com.mx`):

```
>>> data = tldextract.extract('http://example.com.mx')
>>> print '{0}.{1}'.format(data.domain, data.suffix)
example.com.mx
```

Comment: @diegoaguilar sure, it will, give it a try.

Comment: Just curious before trying, what about a .com.mx or a .com.ar?

Comment: @diegoaguilar yup, just checked, see the `UPD`.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://t.co/3hwXTqmktt')
>>> requests.url
>>> r.url
u'http://www.animalpolitico.com/2014/04/304037/#axzz2yETrXxui'
```

Now that you got the url, you can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) to get the components you need.

Answer (score 1):

This applies to Twitter and t.co links specifically, but tweet objects retrieved through the API have what are called entities attached to them.  You'll find the original, expanded version of all URLs contained in a tweet in these entities.  For more info, see: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/entities

Comment: Ups, I should have read the docs deeply ... Btw can you give an eye to this API question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905221/how-to-consume-a-web-api-by-ajax-and-authenticating-by-oauth-first

Comment: Apologies, I can't help with your other question.  I have no experience using OAuth or web services via Ajax/JQueary.