# Why would a button click event cause site to reload in a Bootstrap form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using **jQuery**'s `show()` and `hide()` functions on `divs` in order to *code* or *simulate* different consecutive form sections.

I've made a button that hides a `div` when it's clicked. What's strange is that once the button is clicked, the page will reload and come back to the div shown at first `$(document).ready()`.

What's even more strange is that this problem mentioned above won't happen if you click in the nav bar text before clicking in the "continuar" button (Then the expected page will appear without reloading and showing the first page again).

**The form can be visited here:**

> `http://registropsicologos.maricelaaguilarflores.com:20791`

The blue button is the responsible for the page reload problem, unless you click *Visualizar* at nav bar before clicking in "continuar".

I can't understand why this is happening, I've used `.show()` and `.hide()` before and this problem wasn't happening.

**Here's the relevant JavaScript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    mostrarFormularioRegistro()

    $(".btnSeccion").click(function() {
        btnMostrarSeccion($(this))
    })
})

function mostrarFormularioRegistro () {

    $("#formularioRegistro").show()
    mostrarSeccion(1)
    $("#DB").hide()

}

function mostrarSeccion (seccion) {

    for (var i = 1; i <4; i++) {
        if (i===seccion)
            $("#seccionRegistro"+i).show()
        else
            $("#seccionRegistro"+i).hide()
    }
}

function btnMostrarSeccion (idBtnSeccion) {

    var seccion = parseInt(idBtnSeccion.attr("id").slice(-1))
    if (seccion == 3)
        mostrarSeccion(1)
    else
        mostrarSeccion(seccion+1)

}
```

**This is the body markup:**

```
<body>

    <div class="container" id="proyecto">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Registrar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Visualizar</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="formulario">

        <div class="container" id="seccionRegistro1">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputNombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre(s)</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNombre" placeholder="Nombre(s)">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputApellidos" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Apellidos</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputApellidos" placeholder="Apellidos">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEdad" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Edad</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEdad" placeholder="Apellidos">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputTel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Teléfono</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTel" placeholder="Teléfono">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputCel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Celular</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCel" placeholder="Celular">
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btnSeccion" id="btnSeccion1">Continuar</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="container" id="seccionRegistro2">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEscolaridad" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Escolaridad</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEscolaridad" placeholder="Escolaridad">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputAlmaMater" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Egresado de</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAlmaMater" placeholder="Egresado de">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputAñoEgreso" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Año de egreso</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAñoEgreso" placeholder="Año de egreso">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputCedula" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cédula Profesional</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCedula" placeholder="Cédula Profesional">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="checkPosgrado" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estudios de Posgrado</label>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox"> Sí
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Posgrado" id="inputPosgrado1">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Posgrado" id="inputPosgrado2">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Posgrado" id="inputPosgrado3">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputCedula" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cédula Profesional</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoClinica" value="option1"> Clínica
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoSocial" value="option1"> Social
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoLaboral" value="option1"> Laboral
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoEducativa" value="option1"> Educativa
                  </label>                    
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputTrabajo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Institución de trabajo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTrabajo" placeholder="Institución de trabajo">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="trabajoIndependiente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Desarrollo Profesional Independiente</label>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="trabajoIndependiente"> Sí
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Actividad independiente" id="inputActividadIndependiente1" disabled="true">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Actividad independiente" id="inputActividadIndependiente2" disabled="true">
                      </div>                          
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>        

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="checkPosgrado" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Actividades de trabajo no relacionadas con la psicología</label>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="actividadesAjenasPsicologia"> Sí
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Actividad" id="actividadNoPsicologia1" disabled="true">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Actividad" id="actividadNoPsicologia2" disabled="true">
                      </div>                          
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btnSeccion" id="btnSeccion2">Continuar</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="container" id="seccionRegistro3">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="actividadesInteres" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Actvidades profesionales en las que le gustaría participar</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoClinica" value="option1"> Conferencias y encuentros
                      </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoSocial" value="option1"> Cursos
                      </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoLaboral" value="option1"> Talleres
                      </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoEducativa" value="option1"> Diplomados
                      </label>
                          <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoEducativa" value="option1"> Maestría
                      </label>
                          <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoEducativa" value="option1"> Doctorado
                      </label>                            
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="capacitacionInteres" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Areas de la psicología en las que le gustaría capacitarse</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoClinica" value="Clínica"> Clínica
                      </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoSocial" value="Social"> Social
                      </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoLaboral" value="Laboral"> Laboral
                      </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoEducativa" value="Educativa"> Educativa
                      </label>
                          <label class="checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputAreaTrabajoEducativa" value="Todas"> Todas
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputNombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">¿Alguna temática en particular que le gustaría conocer o capacitarse?</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputInteresCapacitacion" placeholder="Temática de interés">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="checkPosgrado" class="col-sm-2 control-label">¿Pertenece a alguna agrupación relacionada con el campo de la psicología?</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" id="actividadesAjenasPsicologia"> Sí
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Actividad" id="Agrupación" disabled="true">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Actividad" id="Agrupación" disabled="true">
                          </div>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="checkPosgrado" class="col-sm-2 control-label">¿Ha participado con anterioridad en algún evento de la Asociación de Psicólogos de Tuxtepec?</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" id="participacionEventos"> Sí
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select multiple class="form-control" id="eventosAsistidos">
                          <option value="abrazoterapia">Abrazoterapia</option>
                          <option value="tallerMujeres">Taller autoestima mujeres</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <p class="bg-success">

                        ¿Le gustaría pertenecer como miembro activo de la Asociación de Psicólogos de Tuxtepec, A.C. "Manos Unidas por un vivir más pleno?" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="idInteresMiembro"><strong>Sí</strong>
                            </label>

                  </p>

                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btnSeccion" id="btnSeccion3">Continuar</button>
                </div>

                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I checked the url u gave, and its not reloading the page on any of the button click. If you can elaborate what exactly is hapening. As i dont see any postback on any buttons

Comment: God, it's even more strange ... I'm using Google Chrome and you? @KrunalPatil

Comment: .show() and .hide() can't possibly cause the page to reload or change location. most likely instead your clicks are submitting the form because you aren't explicitly preventing that.

Comment: use <input>, as<button> will always give you postback in HTML

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A `<button>` tag uses Submit behavior by default. Thus your page submits the form when the button is clicked and this looks like a page refresh itself. To work around this you can either use an `input` tag

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnSeccion" id="btnSeccion3" value="Continuar"/>
```

to do the same effect. Or you can cancel the Submit in your button's click Event Handler (if that's what you want) like this:

```
$(".btnSeccion").click(function(event) {
    btnMostrarSeccion($(this));
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Thanks!

I will check it now and I'm sure it'll be solved. Was my question really worth -2?

Comment: I just signed up to Stackoverflow and saw your question. So im kinda new. Did I do the -2 by accient? I don't think I down voted anything.

Comment: No, no you didn't .. I had got downvotes, you did an upvote and someone else did too or canceled a downvote.

I complained about it because even simple it might not be that obvious.


It worked like a charm, thanks and welcome to StackOverflow, nice begin!

Comment: I downvoted because *"jQuery .show and .hide functions causing site to reload?"* could have been ruled out by simply removing show and hide...

Comment: Well, I agree for that argument @KevinB. I just really thought it was that and couldn't believe *why*.

I will even change the title so it would help anyone else in future

Comment: Ha ha. You had me worried. Im glad it worked. Thanks @diegoaguilar!

Comment: No worries @SreenathHB ;) What's your expertise development area?

Comment: Well JavaScript jQuery preferably but also ASP.NET and SharePoint too.

Comment: Hey @SreenathHB looking at your site and blog I noticed you've worked with CORS. Can you give an eye to this previous question I've made?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905221/how-to-do-oauth-authentication-via-ajax-jquery

Comment: @diegoaguilar: Coincidentally, I had worked on the same thing last year. So I've posted a reply over there. Signing off for now. Happy coding!

Answer (score 31):

The simplest solution is just adding a simple attribute of "*type*" to the button element, like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="...">My Button</button>
```

When indicating that the button element is specifically from the *type=button*, it will stop acting like a submit button and will not submit (thus, refresh) the current page.

Comment: I can verify that this *doesn't* work all the time. Are you sure your onclick doesn't return false?

Comment: Actually, I haven't been using the "onclick" attribute and just settled for having the "type=button" attribute definition and that does the trick. If the button still submits the form containing it, for some reason, you can always try the "onclick" workaround or the "preventDefault" way inside the code of the click event, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

I have face this issue many times.
Whether using angular, bootstrap or any other js plugin 
sometime it works perfectly on desktop browser but fails to serve the purpose on mobile browsers or touch screen smartphones.

As button tags has a submit behavior by default.

Simplest solution is to use `type="button"`
This will solve the problem otherwise use js to stop submitting of the page.

Answer (score 3):

The following code (from a bootstrap template) can't be changed to an `<input`> tag though. It has the same problem, when running on chrome as Samsung S4 and when running on my actual Samsung S5. Clicking the button to expand the menu causes the page to post-back. I'm not sure if this would also occur on other browsers and models but suspect it would.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

I fixed this by simply adding `onclick="return false;"` into the button tag.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is the elements such as `<button>` has default action of submit, if you want to make them act like normal button specify `type="button"` the default is `type="submit"`

Answer (score 1):

when I changed `<button>` to `<input>` page stopped reloading.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox I think this is not an answer.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [Stack Overflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](//stackoverflow.com/about), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) — small sentences like this one — that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Without jquery (inspired by Sreenath H B):

Setting up clicklistener:

```
submitButton.addEventListener("click", onSubmitClicked);
```

Preventing reload:

```
function onSubmitClicked(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Your code   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `type="button"` and also setting onclick to return false. This works in most browser and on most platforms, but fails in f.x. iPad Air 2 and also Edge sometimes.

Simplest solutions that worked for me is to either use the button outside the form so its not affected by it, or use input with `type=button`.

button even seems to ignore `onsubmit="return false"` on the form too.

This is a very anoying and hard to reproduce error. It works on most things, but all of a sudden breaks on one specific browser/platform combination.